# httpErrors - Redirect 403 to HTML file - How to?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, http-error

I am trying to redirect to a html file when I receive a 403 error in my application. This is handled by IIS, so i have added this into my web config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="File" path="/500.html"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Which gives me this error:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

However if I change the response mode to `ExecuteURL` it will redirect to the page. But it will show a http status code of 200, whereas file will keep the 403 error. I just can't get it to redirect to this file.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the `system.webserver/httperrors/error` configuration node (https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors/error), setting the `responseMode` attribute to `File` requires provding an absolute *Windows* path to the error page. As in the example below:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```